# Seek bar from javascript in WebView

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I want to put this time picker to WebView. http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/
This works, but seekbar (slider with time) did not moved. It moved by click and didn't moved by dragging.
My code is:

```
 webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_calendar_test);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.requestFocusFromTouch();

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
   webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/template11.htm");
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a web environment issue. U need use proper JavaScript or jquery code to handle smooth ness of the slider.. At the max from android environment you can hardware enabled flag for the webview.